# Is this a SQL bug in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

I just found a what i think is a bug in Azure SQL.  Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Any idea what's going on here?

```
create procedure dummyProc
as

declare @myVar nvarchar(20) = 'data'

select myVar = @myVar
into #temp
```

[image]
Executing the code generates an error:

*Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Internal error. Metadata for parameter '@p10c873e7e2034dd29022eb675d63dfbb' in statement or procedure 'CREATE PROCEDURE dummyProc
AS
DECLARE @myVar AS NVARCHAR (20) = @p10c873e7e2034dd29022eb675d63dfbb;
SELECT @myVar AS myVar
INTO   #temp;
' is missing in resultset returned by sp_describe_parameter_encryption.*

Comment: If I separate the the declaration and initialization the error goes away.

Comment: Very strange,I ran you code in SSMS and Portal Query Edit(preview) with no error.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SSMS? Please download the latest.

Comment: I'm running v17.9.1 SSMS.  A coworker is seeing the same issue is using v18.1.

Comment: the database we are using is using always encrypted or (Column Encryption Setting = Enabled).   That by itself doesn't cause the problem, but if you set "Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted" under Query Options-->Advanced you can replicate this issue.

That being said, v18.2 does not appear to be affected.  Updating fixed the issue.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is indeed a problem in SSMS and, sadly, it is still an issue in the latest version of SSMS 18.x.

The issue is that parameterization is trying to parameterize declare statements inside of a create stored proc statement.

We (SSMS Team) will do our best to address it in a future version of SSMS.

In the interim, the suggested way to unblock you would be to disable parametrization, by going to "Tools | Options | Query Execution | SQL Server | Advanced" and making sure that "Enable Parametrization for Always Encrypted" is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to 18.2 fixed the issue.

In earlier versions, using always encrypted with the query option Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted would cause the error.

Thanks for your comments and help!